# In-App Billing Android and bug

Tags: java, android, in-app-billing

Good evening, everybody.
I'm trying to debug the In-App Billing project. The sourse which I use, is

https://github.com/blundell/SimpleInAppPurchaseV3

I'm facing the problem from time to time:
Suddenly the project in file Log.java gives two errors:
1. The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files
The error shows near the first symbol of the file.

1. R.java cannit be resolved! And gen-folder doesn't recreate! No errors in xml-files.
2. IabHelper.java shows the error: The import com.android.vending.billing.IMarketBillingService cannot be resolved
   So if delete com.android.vending.billing/IInAppBillingService.aidl file and recreate it (by copy-paste) nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one.

1) project properties-> java build path-> order and export

```
make sure you have checked true all files that I have listed below:
Android Private Libraries, 
Android Dependencies, 
your all jar and libraries you have added.
```

2) check your SDK manager you have updated all required versions for

```
--> Tools: SDK Tools, SDK platform tools, SDK build tools.
--> Android 4.2 or what ever you are using, Google Map and SDK Platform should be updated latest.
--> Extras: Google Play Services,Google play billing libraries 

also make sure you have not imported wrong variables or any class.
```

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 6):

I think your problem is just the latest update of the SDK.

Test the following operations on two projects :

- In the project properties (eclipse) -> java build path -> order and export make sure that all your jars in the libs folder are checked.
- And "Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties"
- And "Project -> Clean"

If your problem persists try this:

- Remove your project
- Close eclipse
- Import your project again

I hope you have helped!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I did it myriad times:( "java build path  " and  "fix project props" doesn't work! I found very strange and stupid solution (your second solution)- I made the backup of worked version. And restore when I got the problem. I really do not understand why the errors appear. This is very uncomfortable. The debugging is very slow:(

Comment: Doing a 'Clean' on my project forced Eclipse to rebuild the AIDL cache and resolved my issue. Thanks for the post.

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution.
Rename your package name from com.android.vending.billing to com.android.vending.billing2.
Refresh project.
And after that again rename to com.android.vending.billing. And it will work.

Answer (score 1):

In Android Studio click "Make Project" after adding "IInAppBillingService.aidl" file to your project. Then Android Studio can import "IInAppBillingService" class after press Alt+Enter on IInAppBillingService class.